# Mysql: Set time_zone for select queries, UTC for everything else

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to configure MySQL (at runtime) to use UTC for all write queries, but another timezone for all `SELECT` queries?

I'm storing all dates in UTC (additionally, the app will always pass UTC datetimes to MySQL) and have MySQL configured to be running in UTC (using `SET time_zone = '+0:00'`); but is there a way for it to automatically translate all `SELECT` into another timezone?

I realise I can do this in code, but if I can make MySQL do the job for me that'd be much easier.

To be clear: I'd also like to just run a command once, not use any of the date/time formatting functions for each query.

Comment: Perhaps you could read the database's time zone and add/substract according to it?

Answer (score 1):

User CONVERT_TZ() in mysql function

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

Ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Thanks, but this would have to be done *per query*; I'm looking for a solution where I can define it once and MySQL eill apply `TIMEZONE_X` to all `SELECTS`, and UTC to everything else.

Comment: In my project I am using like this let's try for the answer., this will be a good question for us